# Create declaration for an anonymous function export in js file

Tags: typescript

```
module.exports = function (param1, param2) {
return { fun }
 function fun () {
 ...
 }
}
```

How to create typescript declaration file for this JavaScript file.

Comment: What types are the parameters? The return values? Are any of them generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a function that returns an object with a function as one of its properties.

So the type would be:

```
type MyExportedType = (param1: SomeType, param2: SomeType) => {
  fun(): void
}
```